# Does IPFS require Internet access?

Tags: blockchain, ipfs, web3-providers

**Sorry if my question is wrong, I am new to IPFS. Does IPFS require Internet Access mandatorily ?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can find the docs explaining how it works here: https://docs.ipfs.io/concepts/what-is-ipfs/#what-is-ipfs